# Load PHP page content without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load content from a PHP page when user clicks on a link:

The user can click the link to get the AJAX data in the file: `message.php`

I currently have this code in `message.php`

```
            $('#pmid<?php echo $convoData['id']; ?>').click(function(){
                  $.ajax({
                    type:"GET", //this is the default
                    url: "/index.php?i=pm&p=rr",
                    data: {id:"<?php echo $convoData['id']; ?>"}
                  })
                  .done(function( stuff ) {
                  $( "#name" ).html( stuff ); 
                  $( "#post" ).html( otherstuff );
                  $( "")
                  });
              });
```

And the HTML:

```
    Chat with <span id="name"></span> //The $name should be added to here
    <ul id="post"></ul> //The $post should be added to here
```

The page where the AJAX is getting the data from is named: get.php, it looks like this:

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $get=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE id='$id'");
    $getData=mysql_fetch_assoc($get);


    //Set the variables that needs to be send back to the other page.
    $getUser=$user->getUserData($getData['sender_id']);


    $name=$getUser['username'];
    $post = '
    <li>
      <img width="30" height="30" src="images/avatar-male.jpg">
      <div class="bubble">
        <a class="user-name" href="">'.$name.'</a>
        <p class="message">
          '.$getData['subject'].'
        </p>
        <p class="time">

        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    ';
echo $name;
echo $post;
```

So, the problem is that currently all the data is just being printed in `#name`

How can I do so the `$name` will get printed in `#name` and the `$post` in `#post`?

Comment: retun the output as a json encoded array with two keys and on the response show the values based on keys

Comment: have you tried retrieving a json encoded array from the php page then splitting the data using jquery and allocating to the right container

Comment: How do I do that? Could one of you make an example of that?

Comment: `echo '{ "name" : "'.$name.'", "post" : "'.$post'" }';` Or be lazy and use json_encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the output as a json encoded array with two keys and on the response show the values based on keys like this

In your php

```
$arrRet = array();
$arrRet['name'] = $name;
$arrRet['post'] = $post;
echo json_encode($arrRet); 
die();
```

In the ajax

```
$.ajax({
     type:"GET",
     url: "/index.php?i=pm&p=rr",
     dataType:'json',
     data: {id:"<?php echo $convoData['id']; ?>"},
     success : function(res){
       if(res){
        $( "#name").html(res.name); 
        $( "#post").html(res.post);
       }
     }
});
```

Comment: check in the browser console for if you have any erros or the request is triggering

Comment: Is the ajax request happening.?if yes What is the response.?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use json to pass the two variables:

JS:

```
$('#pmid<?php echo $convoData['id']; ?>').click(function(){
                  $.ajax({
                    type:"GET", //this is the default
                    url: "/index.php?i=pm&p=rr",
                    data: {id:"<?php echo $convoData['id']; ?>",},
                    dataType: 'json'
                  })
                  .done(function( stuff ) {
                  $( "#name" ).html( stuff[0] ); 
                  $( "#post" ).html( stuff[1] );
                  $( "")
                  });
              });
```

PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array($name,$post));
```

Answer (score 0):

try returning it like this:

```
$output = array();
$output['name'] = $name;
$output['post'] = $post;
$output = json_encode($output);
echo json_encode($output); exit;
```

Then with the return in js try :

```
function(data){
     $( "#name" ).html( data.name ); 
     $( "#post" ).html( data.post );
}
```